# Distance of scaled point on the unit sphere to an integer

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S:=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^d:||x||_2=1\}$ be the d-dimensional unit sphere, where $||x||_2$ is the euclidean norm.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $s\in S$ be an arbitrary point on the sphere.

Is it correct that there exists an $\alpha>0$ and a $k\in \mathbb{Z}^d\setminus\{0\}$ such that the
distance between $\alpha s-k$ is less than $\epsilon$?

In other words can i scale every point on the unit sphere such that the distance to an non-zero integer is arbitrarily small

Comment: This genre of question is very interesting, and possibly subtler than some people might have supposed. If no one who has a sharper answer responds after a while, I will tell what I know.... such as it is. :)

Comment: I think this is related to [Kronecker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_theorem)

Comment: A quick comment, along the lines of @GabrielC.Barbosa's comment: for situations more complicated than products of circles, Kronecker's theorem becomes "Weyl's criterion" for equidistribution. Kloosterman and others in the early 20th century treated this issue on _spheres_, in various dimensions, with _odd_ ambient dimensions being more complicated, as half-integer-weight modular forms enter, etc. More later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true for any vector $v\in\mathbb R^d$, not necessarily on the unit sphere. For any $x\in\mathbb R^d$, let $x\text{ mod }\mathbb Z^d$ denote the unique element in $y\in [0, 1)^d$ such that $x-y\in\mathbb Z^d$.

Because $[0, 1)^d$ is bounded, the sequence $\{nv \text{ mod } \mathbb Z^d\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{n_iv\text{ mod } \mathbb Z^d \mid i\in\mathbb N\}$. In particular, for large enough $i>j$, there is $\|n_i v \text{ mod } \mathbb Z^d - n_j v \text{ mod } \mathbb Z^d \|= \|(n_i-n_j) v \text{ mod } \mathbb Z^d\|<\epsilon$. That is $(n_i-n_j)v$ is very close to an integral point, and we may take $\alpha = n_i - n_j$ (in particular $\alpha$ can be chosen as an integer).

Note that $\alpha$ can be taken to be as large as needed, and when $\alpha$ is large, $\|\alpha v\|$ is not close to $0$, so the $k$ can always be taken to be nonzero.

Also the same argument applies to any lattice with compact quotient, not necessarily $\mathbb Z^d$.